# Visual Studio 2010 restart debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS2008 I could start the debugger (F5) and make changes then re-start the debugger without having to completely stop debugging and then restart. I cannot find the icon or the keyboard-equivalent shortcut for this action in VS2010.

Comment: You are talking about Edit + Continue, it doesn't restart the debugger.  Set the platform target to x86.

Answer (score 2):

Default is Ctrl+Shift+F5, however you can remap it in Tools - Options - Environment - Keyboard. Search for `Debug.Restart` command. The icon looks as following in the Debug toolbar:

[image].

This toolbar only appears when you are in debug mode. It is actually same in VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to 'Edit And Continue' ?

To enable it:

> On the Tools menu, click Options. In the Options dialog box, open the
>   Debugging node, and select the Edit and Continue category. To enable,
>   select the Enable Edit and Continue check box. To disable, clear the
>   check box.

Note that if you're using a 64 bit PC, you will have to explicitly set the platform target to x86 instead of Any CPU as [Edit And Continue isn't available on 64 bit machines.](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/431200/edit-and-continue-is-not-allowed-when-debugging-a-64-bit-application)

Answer (score 0):

I allways do it with ctrl+shift+f5, I don't know if it's another way to do it